# Using Linked Server TO Oracle for Insert, Update, Delete

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, linked-server

I have an active Linked Server to an Oracle database and can select data without issue. I need to use this linked server to update, insert, or delete rows FROM the Oracle tables.

I have run at least a dozen different code snippets from StackOverflow in an attempt to make this work. None have. Details:

Sql Sever version 2014
Oracle version 11g
Linked Sever to Oracle name: CMDB

Code samples:

```
DELETE OPENQUERY ("CMDB", 'SELECT * FROM CMDB.CAMPAIGN 
                  WHERE CAMPAIGNIDGUID = ''{6477D6C6-5783-E511-B2E7-005056952C45}''')
```

> Error: OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "CMDB" returned message "艂_".
>   OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "CMDB" returned message "ROW-00054: Message 54 not found; No message file for product=OLEDB, facility=OraOLEDB (OS 193)".
>   Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot execute the query "SELECT * FROM CMDB.CAMPAIGN WHERE CAMPAIGNIDGUID = '{6477D6C6-5783-E511-B2E7-005056952C45}'" against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "CMDB".

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("CMDB", 'SELECT * FROM CMDB.CAMPAIGN')
```

> Error: None, returned 83 rows of data

Notes: We CANNOT use SSIS. This is in a very restrictive environment and we are limited on what we can use. This is being developed for a job that will PUSH production data from a Sql Server database TO an Oracle schema. All assistance is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's a common problem with Oracle linked servers. I used a solution using `INSTEAD OF TRIGGERS`. It's kind of hack and not each version of Oracle can be used. If you interested I can describe it.

Comment: Are you sure the account being used by the Linked Server connection has access on the Oracle side to perform deletes?

Comment: This link suggests not having quotes around your linked server name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You can query this table to check perms: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(CMDB, 'SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS')`